# How to run multiple instances of nutch?

Tags: nutch

I want to crawl multiple websites by simultaneously running multiple instances of apache nutch-1.6. Should I install multiple copy of apache nutch in different locations and create a single(or master) .sh file for executing nutch crawl command for every copy? OR is it possible to configure a single copy of nutch for multiple instances?

Comment: Is it possible to simultaneously execute shell scripts located in different directories from a single shell script?

Comment: If you intend to use nutch on a single box, you don't really have to run multible instances of nutch since you can use threading and -nicely- you can have a control over it, i am using nutch 2.x "not reallt sure if this would apply at your case though" and to do such a functionality during fetching time i changed the values of "*fetcher.threads.fetch*" and "*fetcher.threads.per.queue*" in *nutch-site.xml* file to something other than the default which was "1", those config items tell nutch how many threads to execute while running the fetcher job.

Comment: I have to run nutch on multiple machines so that I can speed up crawling. How I'll do it. I could not found any single complete guide on web

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'bin/crawl' script. Ran it in 2 different terminals simultaneously. Both finished their execution without any bug (atleast as per my judgment). **I had supplied different seed directory and crawl directory to each simultaneous instance.**

However as per an another [thread here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Concurrently-running-multiple-nutch-crawls-td3166207.html) it states that you must run bin/nutch command by supplying different 'configuration' file every time you want to run a different simultaneous instance and supply a different /tmp/ path for each instance. I myself didnt had to go through that trouble. The above method worked pretty well for me